# Chat room in Thunderbird with Google Chat

Tags: thunderbird, google-talk, xmpp

How do I start a chat room in Thunderbird with Google Chat? What values do I use for room and server?

[image: Imgur]

Thunderbird 17.0.3.

Comment: Wow, Room: private-chat-1aafa6b0-89f8-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66 and Server: groupchat.google.com worked! Peculiar. So how do I invite people to the chat? Thunderbird doesn't seem to have an invite function.

Comment: I have added it as an answer below. As for inviting people, perhaps you can try asking them to use the exact same room name and server at their end while signing in. If that doesn't help, post a new question because I've never used Google Chat in Thunderbird. I just guessed that what works for iChat might also work for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **server** use **groupchat.google.com**.

For **room**, you need to create a UUID by using an offline or [online utility](http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen), then enter **private-chat-*UUID*** as the room name (obviously replace ***UUID*** with the actual one you generated).
<sub>[Source](http://amitparekh.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/group-chat-chat-room-in-ichat-using-google-talk/)</sub>

---

Edit: To invite others to your newly created private chat room you'll need to send them the exact same room name and server you used (confirmed to work [here](https://superuser.com/questions/586597/#comment719179_586597)). Unfortunately, as long as Google Chat in Thunderbird lacks an **Invite** option this roundabout way seems to be the only solution.