# How do I invite people to a chat room in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, chat

Following instructions from this SuperUser post: [Chat room in Thunderbird with Google Chat](https://superuser.com/questions/563384/chat-room-in-thunderbird-with-google-chat) I created a chat room in Thunderbird using my Google Talk account.

How can I invite people to this chat room? I've looked all around for an invite option but haven't found anything.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my comment there?

Comment: Karen, I did, and that did work for creating the chat group, but I can't figure out how to invite anyone else to it. I can send the group name/server name around, but that's not the easiest for everyone that I'm sending it to to understand.

Comment: Yeah, but still, have you tried and does it work? If there's no invite option I'm not sure what other choice you have. In any case I'm confused by how a chat client can be so limited as to require people to jump through hoops to do this. Perhaps it's not a properly implemented feature still and you're not supposed to use private chat rooms in TB after all...

Comment: Yes, that did work. But no, I don't see a way to invite people, which is odd.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll update my answer accordingly.